# How to save an excel file in the "text" format in Oracle PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracleforms

I have written a code in the **WHEN BUTTEN PRESSED** trigger of a button exists in my form. The code saves an excel file and is like bellow:

```
DECLARE
    OUT_FILE TEXT_IO.FILE_TYPE;
    ---
    CURSOR CUR_1  IS 
    SELECT  V.NO        ,
            V.DATE          
              
    FROM    V_RECEIPT V 
    ---
BEGIN   
    OUT_FILE := TEXT_IO.FOPEN('D:\EXPORT_EXCEL\'||:GLOBAL.USRNAME||'.CSV','W'); 
    ---
    TEXT_IO.PUT(OUT_FILE,'SEP = ;');    
    TEXT_IO.NEW_LINE(OUT_FILE);
    
    TEXT_IO.PUT(OUT_FILE,' NO_RECEIPT ; DATE_RECEIPT ');    

    TEXT_IO.NEW_LINE(OUT_FILE);
        ---
    FOR X IN CUR_1 LOOP

        TEXT_IO.PUT(OUT_FILE, '00001'      || ';' ); 

        TEXT_IO.PUT(OUT_FILE, X.DATE              ); 
        ---
        TEXT_IO.NEW_LINE(OUT_FILE);
    END LOOP;
    ---
    TEXT_IO.FCLOSE(OUT_FILE);
    ---
END;
```

The problem is that in the output excel file, the column which is specified to be a text as "00001", is saved as "1". I don't know weather there is a way to determine the excel cells format as 'text', or not.
Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Is it actually saved as 1 in the text file if you view that with a text editor; or only displayed as 1 in Excel, which is a known issue/feature?

Comment: @AlexPoole It's only displayed as '1' in excel, I want it to be saved and displayed as '00001' in excel.

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/318420/45140

Comment: Excel is not a text aditor, so data displayed and actual data are different

Comment: @AlexPoole So many thanks to you! It finally works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To interpret the values as a string and not convert them to the data types other than string in the .CSV file, write the code like this:

```
TEXT_IO.PUT(OUT_FILE, '"=""00001"""'                || ';' );
```

and this:

```
TEXT_IO.PUT(OUT_FILE, '"=""' || X.DATE || '"""' || ';' );
```